# Replacing the ESC button on a NSTouchBar

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstouchbar

I am building a `NSTouchBar` for my app using storyboard.

I want to replace the `ESC` button with something else.

As usual, there is no doc telling you how to do that.

I have searched the web and I have found vague informations like

> You can change the content of "esc" to something else, though, like
>   "done" or anything, even an icon, by using
>   escapeKeyReplacementItemIdentifier with the NSTouchBarItem.

But this is too vague to understand.

Any ideas?

---

This is what I did so far.

I have added a button to `NSTouchBar` on storyboard and changed its identifier to `newESC`. I added this line programmatically:

```
self.touchBar.escapeKeyReplacementItemIdentifier = @"newESC";
```

When I run the App the `ESC` key is now invisible but still occupies its space on the bar. The button that was supposed to replace it, appears next to it. So that bar that was

```
`ESC`, `NEW_ESC`, `BUTTON1`, `BUTTON2`, ...
```

is now

```
`ESC` (invisible), `NEW_ESC`, `BUTTON1`, `BUTTON2`, ...
```

The old `ESC` is still occupying its space on the bar.

Comment: The header NSTouchBar.h has some attempt at documentation. The comments aren't proper headerdocs, so I guess they didn't make it to the published docset.

Comment: Apple should refrain from writing docs, they are all crap. I have read that and still don't know how to do it.

Comment: "should refrain" I mean, they basically already do! :P

Comment: I mean completely. It is obvious by now that they treat developers as 3rd class citizens. They despise us and MacOS developers even more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by creating a touch bar item, let's say a `NSCustomTouchBarItem` containing a `NSButton`, and associating this item with its own identifier.

Then with *another* identifier you do your usual logic but you add the previously created identifier as the ESC replacement.

Quick example in Swift:

```
func touchBar(_ touchBar: NSTouchBar, makeItemForIdentifier identifier: NSTouchBarItemIdentifier) -> NSTouchBarItem? {

    switch identifier {
    case NSTouchBarItemIdentifier.identifierForESCItem:
        let item = NSCustomTouchBarItem(identifier: identifier)
        let button = NSButton(title: "Button!", target: self, action: #selector(escTapped))
        item.view = button
        return item
    case NSTouchBarItemIdentifier.yourUsualIdentifier:
        let item = NSCustomTouchBarItem(identifier: identifier)
        item.view = NSTextField(labelWithString: "Example")
        touchBar.escapeKeyReplacementItemIdentifier = .identifierForESCItem
        return item
    default:
        return nil
    }

}

func escTapped() {
    // do additional logic when user taps ESC (optional)
}
```

I also suggest making an extension (category) for the identifiers, it avoids making typos with string literals:

```
@available(OSX 10.12.2, *)
extension NSTouchBarItemIdentifier {
    static let identifierForESCItem = NSTouchBarItemIdentifier("com.yourdomain.yourapp.touchBar.identifierForESCItem")
    static let yourUsualIdentifier = NSTouchBarItemIdentifier("com.yourdomain.yourapp.touchBar.yourUsualIdentifier")
}
```

Comment: haha... things are getting worse... I have created [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44866666/make-a-nsobject-class-be-the-nextresponder-is-that-possible-or-is-that-anothe) to deal with the fact that the `NSTouchBar` delegate methods are not firing... if I solve this other one, your question will probably work and it will solve this question... it is a combo... 

Comment: btw what is `yourUsualIdentifier` and shouldn't´t you be calling `touchBar.escapeKeyReplacementItemIdentifier` from inside the first case block, the block that represents the esc?

Comment: yourUsualIdentifier is just an example of another identifier for an item, here a text field. And since the ESC replacement is a property on the `touchbar`, it doesn't matter where you call it from.

Comment: An objective.c version? Thanks